Navigating to a top level destination doesn't save all toplevel states
Problem
There are three navigation graphs in my app as nested navigations : HomeGraph, ProfileGraph and MenuGraph. I want to achieve that when you navigate between these graphs through the BottomNavigationBar each of them must preserve their states and be added to app's backstack properly so that UX won't be affected in a bad way. But when I use the method in official docs, it only preserves the HomeGraph's state and not the others. I want it to save and restore each and every one of TopLevelDestination
Here is the minimum reproducer project: https://github.com/sevbanBayir/NestedGraphExp
The method that recommended in docs and i used to preserve state navigating between screens:
fun NavController.navigateToTopLevelDestination(topLevelDestination: TopLevelDestination) {
    navigate(topLevelDestination.route) {
        popUpTo(graph.findStartDestination().id) {
            saveState = true
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
    }
}

My navigation setup:
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Destination.HomeDestination.HomeGraph,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)
) {
    homeGraph(navController)
    profileGraph(navController)
    menuGraph(navController)
}

And each graph looks like this:
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation<HomeDestination.HomeGraph>(startDestination = HomeDestination.Home1) {
        composable<HomeDestination.Home1> {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(HomeDestination.Home1.toString())
                Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(HomeDestination.Home2) }) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
        }

        composable<HomeDestination.Home2> {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(HomeDestination.Home2.toString())
                Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(HomeDestination.Home3) }) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
        }

        composable<HomeDestination.Home3> {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(HomeDestination.Home3.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}


Finally these are my TopLevelDestination definitions:
enum class TopLevelDestination(val route: Destination, val icon: ImageVector) {
    HOME(Destination.HomeDestination.HomeGraph, icon = Icons.Default.Home),
    PROFILE(Destination.ProfileDestination.ProfileGraph, icon = Icons.Default.Person),
    MENU(Destination.MenuDestination.MenuGraph, icon = Icons.Default.Menu)
}

